# How to rename app.js file in index.html using VueCli 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

VueCli3 automatically add app.js in index.html. I want to rename that app.js file some other name. Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a file called `vue.config.js` in your project root directory and, in the `configureWebpack` property, you can set the name for the output js file.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {

    configureWebpack: {

        output: {

            filename: "appname.js"

        },

    },

}
```